# Await Keeps on Waiting - React, React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, truffle

I am using Truffle React Box. When I use React Router to open a component. Await in ComponentDidMount doesn't return anything. However, after refreshing page, it works fine.

This is my code:

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
        console.log("1");
        const web3 = await getWeb3();
        console.log("2")
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        const Contract = truffleContract(PrototypeStateContract);
        Contract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
        const instance = await Contract.deployed();
        this.setState({ web3, accounts, contract: instance });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(
        `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.`
      );
      console.log(error);
    }
};
```

When using react router "Link to" to access a component, only "1" gets printed.

When refreshing the same page, both "1" and "2" gets printed as expected.

How can I solve this?

Comment: what is `getWeb3` - perhaps the Promise it returns is never resolved - that would make await await forever

Comment: @Bravo The getWeb3 code can be found here: https://github.com/truffle-box/react-box/blob/master/client/src/utils/getWeb3.js .

Comment: and that code awaits other promises ... so ... I'd do some debugging console.log's to see where the code is failing ... at a guess, for some reason window load event has already fired before you add the event listener, and therefore none of the code in getWeb3 ever runs ... put a `console.log('something')` above `if (window.ethereum) {` - if that never outputs, then you've found the issue

Comment: Ok Thanks @bravo . Will try that

Comment: probably considered "hacky" - but I'd add `window.loadHasFired = new Promise(resolve => window.addEventListener('load', resolve));` somewhere at the top of `<head>` and then instead of using window load handler, you can `window.loadHasFired.then(() => { /* code that depends on window load having fired */});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved after making these changes to getWeb3.js.

```
import Web3 from "web3";

const getWeb3 = () =>
  new Promise( async(resolve, reject) => {
    // Wait for loading completion to avoid race conditions with web3 injection timing.
      // Modern dapp browsers...
      if (window.ethereum) {
        const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        try {
          // Request account access if needed
          await window.ethereum.enable();
          // Acccounts now exposed
          resolve(web3);
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
      }
      // Legacy dapp browsers...
      else if (window.web3) {
        // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
        const web3 = window.web3;
        console.log("Injected web3 detected.");
        resolve(web3);
      }
      // Fallback to localhost; use dev console port by default...
      else {
        const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
          "http://127.0.0.1:9545"
        );
        const web3 = new Web3(provider);
        console.log("No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.");
        resolve(web3);
      }

  });

export default getWeb3;
```

I have removed the event listener as window doesn't load when accessing from react-router Link.